# problem with login

Tags: 14.04, login, laptop

When I close the lid of Laptop and then open it a message asks about password when I enter pass, Ubuntu login screen will come after that. I have to enter my pass twice to login. I can't remember but I think it happened after installing xfce.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Is it Xscreensaver that asks for the first password? If so, you can get rid of that if you have no need for screensavers by doing:

```
sudo apt-get purge xscreensaver
```

Comment: It is  still there.

Comment: In Settings under System there is an entry called  'Session and Startup'. Look in there in the Advanced Tab if you have "Lock Screen before Sleep" checked